# how to get RecyclerView highlighed selection changed from outside of RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have made horizontal RecyclerView to show images where you select different actions by touching image. I have also highlighted current active selection by using background drawable and set that on onBindViewHolder.

```
   public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.itemView.setSelected(selectedPos == position);
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(horizontalList.get(position).imageId);
```

then i have button which is not part RecyclerView so you can also roll selection in recyclerview to next one by pressing it.
It's working fine except highlighting doesn't change when pressing button.
I can test that when selecting currently selected item, i get my instructions activity opened otherwise different activity will be opened.

So how i can get that current selected item highlight when pressing a button??

**update 1.**

I have in my activity under myButtonOnClick

```
int mItemCount = horizontalAdapter.getItemCount() - 1;
horizontalAdapter.notifyItemChanged(selectedItem); 
if (selectedItem == mItemCount) { 
   selectedItem = 0;
} else { 
   selectedItem += 1; 
}
horizontalAdapter.notifyItemChanged(selectedItem);
```

which doesn't do much.

**update 2.**

Found the problem which was at my onBindViewHolder as i declared there different variable which messed things up.
so horizontalAdapter.notifyItemChanged(selectedItem); worked just fine and my 
onBindViewHolder now i have holder.itemView.setSelected(selectedItem == position);
so manipulate same variable from both button and recyclerview to get things right.

Comment: If I'm understanding your problem correctly, can't you just `selectedPos++` and then `notifyDatasetChanged()`?

Comment: @billynomates Well that isn't the problem how i change selected item but the problem is that i don't get my selected item highlighted even selection is correctly changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an OnScrollListener to your RecyclerView to observe any change in scroll state and position.

ref to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#addOnScrollListener(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.OnScrollListener))

If it doesn't help, you may paste your code inside the `button.OnClickListener` for further discussion.

Comment: scrolling is working so that i can scroll images and then select desired item and it will be highlighted. Not sure if i understood usage of OnScrollListener on this.

But when button is pressed which is outside of RecyclerView. If i implement button.OnClickListener at RecyclerView then it will override myButtonOnClick from activity.